# Configuring properties from config.json using services.Configure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, config.json

Following on from a StackOverflow question regarding [Using IConfiguration globally in mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179370/using-iconfiguration-globally-in-mvc6). A comment to the accepted answer suggests using

```
services.Configure<SomeOptions>(Configuration);
```

Now this works fine with the following code;

**Class**

```
public class SomeOptions
{
    public string MyOption { get; set; }
}
```

**config.json**

```
{
    "MyOption": "OptionValue"
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{        
    services.Configure<SomeOptions>(Configuration);
}
```

However the `config.json` file doesn't have any really structure, and I would like it to look more like;

```
{
    "SomeOptions": {
        "MyOption": "OptionValue"
    }
}
```

However this does not bind the values within the class. Is there anyway to allow this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the `config.json` structure you also need to change your **class structure**.

```
{
    "SomeOptions": {
        "MyOption": "OptionValue"
    }
}
```

maps to something like

```
public class SomeOptions
{
    public List<MyOption> MyOptions { get; set; }
}

public class MyOption
{
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What you have suggested. `MyOptions` is null

Answer (score 2):

You can access specific value in config.json like:

```
Configuration.Get("SomeOptions:MyOption");
```

Which returns

```
"OptionValue"
```

So, your code will be

```
services.Configure<SomeOptions>(options => 
        options.MyOption = Configuration.Get("SomeOptions:MyOption"));
```

Comment: Hi Master19, thanks. I am looking to do it without "magic strings" though.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.Configure<SomeOptions>(Configuration.GetSubKey(nameof(SomeOptions)));
```

Should do it.