# How to properly read nested configuration values from config.json in ASP.NET5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, config.json

I was following some [examples for ASP.NET 5](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html) and I got stumbled with how to properly read "nested" configuration values (if that is the proper term).

Here is relevant portion of `config.json`:

```
{
    "ApplicationName" : "OwNextApp",
    "AppSettings": {
        "SiteTitle": "OwNext"
    },
}
```

And relevant portion of `HomeController.cs`:

```
public IActionResult About()
{
    var appNestedNameFailed = _config.Get("AppSettings.SiteTitle");
    var appNestedNameSuccess = _config.Get("AppSettings:SiteTitle");
    var appName = _config.Get("ApplicationName");
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format(@"Your 
        APP NAME: {0};
        APP NESTED NAME FAILED: {1}; 
        APP NESTED NAME SUCCESS: {2}", 
            appName, appNestedNameFailed, appNestedNameSuccess);

    return View();
}
```

Value for `appNestedNameFailed` is empty (my initial try before research). And `appNestedNameSuccess` has value; after I did research and found in tests for [Configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.FunctionalTests/ConfigurationTests.cs) (relevant code shown):

```
// Assert
Assert.Equal("IniValue1", config.Get("IniKey1"));
Assert.Equal("IniValue2", config.Get("IniKey2:IniKey3"));
```

Can someone explain why is this the case? Why would it make sense to use `:` over `.`? From my interaction with JSON data usually `.` notation works fine, e.g. [How to access nested json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463233/how-to-access-nested-json-data).

Also, I found similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318935/configuring-properties-from-config-json-using-services-configure) but this does not give explanation of why `:` was chosen.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's the convention that we decided upon when we first created the configuration model. We started with json in mind and `:` is the delimiter there.

Anyways, if you don't want to worry about those conventions, I recommend using the [ConfigurationBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder) which binds a configuration to a model (a strong type object). [Here are the tests on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/test/Config.Binder.Test/ConfigurationBinderTests.cs) that can serve as example.

Comment: So as suspected, it was just the natural delimiter. Thanks for confirming :)

Comment: Thanks all. I like strongly typed so I use `ConfigurationBinder`.

Comment: fyi, links are dead

Comment: Thanks @RSid. I fixed the links

Comment: links are dead again :(

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci : Sorry to bump you, but the link you provided are now dead :\

Comment: I fixed the links (again)

Answer (score 19):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

var connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");

// or

var connectionString2= configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "myconnection"
  },
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure "GetSection" should be in there twice for connectionString2 at the bottom of the first code section.

Comment: @PaulSchroeder You can stack .GetSection("sectionName") as many times as required - the path remains the same, with each section separated by a : character.

Answer (score 1):

Peering deep into the bowels of the [JsonConfigurationFileParser](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blame/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs#L110) source with blame on for the enter/exit methods that look at:

```
private void VisitJObject(JObject jObject)
{
    foreach (var property in jObject.Properties())
    {
        EnterContext(property.Name);
        VisitProperty(property);
        ExitContext();
    }
}

private void EnterContext(string context)
{
    _context.Push(context);
    _currentPath = string.Join(":", _context.Reverse());
}

private void ExitContext()
{
    _context.Pop();
    _currentPath = string.Join(":", _context.Reverse());
}
```

it seems that the ASP.NET team should leave more illuminating check-in comments :).

My best guess is that there could be data stored in the config.json file that would need to have a `.` in it, whereas `:` would be less common.  For instance:

```
"AppSettings": {
    "Site.Title": "Is .NET getting faster?"
},
```

It's a bad example, but it seems reasonable that they wanted to be as "safe" as possible and use something outside of the norm.  If you wanted to store a type's full name, that would also be slightly easier without needing to worry about a stray period.

```
"AppSettings": {
    "ImportantTypeName": "WebApp.CoolStuff.Helpers.AwesomeClass"
},
```

Comment: That seems reasonable, and is what I thought as well. But, I was hoping for something more enlightening. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Looking more at this config.json, I think that they chose `:` because that is used to nest data, e.g. `"AppSettings": {`. Anyway.

Comment: It is typical to nest objects in json with `:` since it denotes a key/value pair.  As a result, it probably ended up being the most natural delimiter.  Sorry I couldn't uncover a more official answer for you :).