# DotNet Core - Connection String from Class Library

Tags: .net-core

I have my connection string to SQL stored in the Web project in appsettings.json

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbConnectionString": "***"
  },
```

Then I added a DB context using Scaffold

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "name=MyDbConnectionString" -Provider "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"  ...  -Force
```

I can use the context in a controller and I have no issues getting data or writing.  However, I would like all my business logic to be on a separate class library. So here is my repository from my Library:

```
    public class MyRepository
{

    private static MyContext CurrentContext
    {
        get { return new MyContext(); }
    }

    public static async void AddEventLog(EventLog eventLog)
    {
        using (var context = CurrentContext)
        {
            context.EventLog.Add(eventLog);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails when it tries to write to the DB.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'A named connection string was used, but the name 'MyDbConnectionString' was not found in the application's configuration.
```

Should I be adding appsettings.json to the library project (This seems redundant, and incorrect)?  What am I missing?  How do I reference back to the web projects appsettings.json file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my startup

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnectionString")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***** HERE ARE CHANGES I HAVE MADE TO THE WORK *****

I have found the issue I believe so here we go.

1. Remove the following from MySsdCaseContext.

   ```
   public MySsdCaseContext()
   {
   }
   ```

   and keep this one..

   ```
    public MySsdCaseContext(DbContextOptions<MySsdCaseContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }
   ```
2. For the purposes of fixing this comment out the following from OnConfiguring.

   ```
   if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
       {
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=MySsdCaseDb");
       }
   ```
3. In startup.cs add the following inside ConfigureService method.

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<MySsdCaseContext>(options 
   =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySsdCaseDb")));
   ```

This should prompt you to add a reference to MySsdCase.Core.Data class library. You don't currently have this. Basically put
the following at the top of startup.cs

```
    using MySsdCase.Core.Data;
```

4. Ensure the following is inside MySsdCase.Web.cspoj

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\MySsdCase.Core\MySsdCase.Core.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
5. Do it like this...

   ```
         public class EventLogRepository 
       {
   private readonly MySsdCaseContext _context;

   public async Task AddEventLogAsync(EventLog eventLog)
   {

       var myVar = await _context.Set<ClientDetails>()
           .AsNoTracking()
           .Select(p => p)
           .Take(2)
           .ToListAsync();
   }
   }
   ```

I think overall there was no reference to the DAL from the BL in startup.cs.

Comment: I had AddDbContext in the startup and I did not post in my question.   I edited my post and added.  However, you recommended to use AddDbContextPool and I tried using that and I still get the same error.  BTW.. The Connection string is working since I can use it from the controller.  Error is just when I use it from the Class Library.

Comment: I have been struggling to figure this out for a while now... I believe I have narrowed down what I am looking for to be how do I pass the connection string thorough DI to my repository.  I have tried the answer on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058497/dependency-injection-with-netcore-for-dal-and-connection-string  but I am still having trouble.

Comment: Nevermind... In the index I was not passing the context in this call: _eventRepo = new EventLogRepository(context);  @Bazza I really appreciate the help!  Thanks Again!