# How can I use config.json to set environment-specific variables for a Visual Studio 2015/DNX project?

Tags: c#, json, azure, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution made up of projects targeting DNX framework. I have been working locally but I plan to deploy to Azure environments (dev/test/prod).  Naturally, the solution uses different database connection strings and other variables dependent on the environment.  In the past I made use of cloud configuration files to set these variables, reading them with the `CloudConfigurationManager`.

I am given to understand that I need to use a config.json file.  I have the following code in my Startup.cs file:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment app)
{
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder(app.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    Configuration.Set("ASPNET_ENV", "Development");
}
```

My config.json file is currently an empty object `{ }`.  How do I add variables to this file (syntax?), and how do I access them from code?

Comment: Have you read through http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html? You've already got code to load an environment-specific JSON file - do you *have* such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this line in your startup code:

```
.AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
```

This adds an additional JSON config file which is named depending on your environment name. So add a new file to your project called:

```
config.<environment-name>.json
```

And set up the details in there, such as:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "SomeVariable": "Blah"
  },
  "Data": {
    "YourConnectionString": {
      "ConnectionString": "<connection string here>"
    }
  }
}
```

For reading the configuration, there's a good answer here: [Using IConfiguration globally in mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179370/using-iconfiguration-globally-in-mvc6)

Comment: Thanks DavidG.  I followed the example in the answer you linked to, but it seems overly cumbersome - is it really necessary to have an "options" class and add every single configuration key to my ConfigureServices method in my startup class?  Can't I just read directly from the file, or is this bad practice?

Comment: There is a lot more code in the answer I linked but overall it's a pretty way of doing things. Once you get your head round DI, it's actually pretty simple.

Comment: As for being bad practice, it's not really bad to read from the file directly, but what happens if in future you decide to move the config to a database for example? Using this method it's a simple change of one file but if you read directly from the file all over your code, you will have many more changes to make and test.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, I see the error of my ways.  It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain old JSON for that. For example, here's how to define a connection string:

```
{
  "Foo": "Bar"
}
```

To access the configuration value, you do:

```
config.Get("username")
```

or:

```
config["username"];
```

You can find more information here: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Comment: Triple backticks don't work in Stack Exchange markdown - just indent the block of code (or JSON, or whatever) to format it.

Comment: Thanks Erik, but I don't understand how you got the `config` variable?  Also, I take it "username" should be "Foo" in order to get the string "Bar"?